# Oracle SQL - Group by distinct columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a query that is being created dynamically based on a different query (a string) which is passed in. In the below, the string being passed in to generate the query is the quoted parameter of `dbms_xmlgen.get_xmltype` (The quoted query is irrelevant to answering the question, I am looking to change the outer query)

```
SELECT s.value AS "value"
         ,im.sequence AS "sequence"
         ,lookup_detail_lib.get_type_value_message AS "prefix"
         ,lookup_detail_lib.get_type_value_message AS "suffix"
         ,im.field AS "field"
    FROM xmltable('for $i in ./ROWSET/ROW/* return $i' passing
                  dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('SELECT blah blah this generates a clob') columns
                  column_name VARCHAR2(100) path 'local-name()'
                 ,VALUE CLOB path 'text()') s
        ,info_metadata im
        ,task t
        ,job j
   WHERE im.column_name = s.column_name
     AND im.job_type = j.job_type
     AND j.job_id = t.job_id
     AND NVL(im.task_type, t.task_type) = t.task_type
     AND t.task_id = 13580
   ORDER BY im.sequence;
```

The  result of this query is:

[image]

However my desired result would put the column `im.sequence` in this order: 1,2,3,4,2,3,4 (rather than the shown 1,2,2,3,3,4,4). My question is, is there a way I could sort of group these so that they are in order of distinct ascending `im.sequence`? Note: For further clarification, I am looking to manipulate the outside query, I cannot change the inner quoted query. Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: How does the "1" get duplicated?

Comment: My bad, I edited the question to show the actual sequence it should show. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by sequence order by sequence) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by sequence;
```

This does not duplicate the "1" row but it does sort the rest as you desire.